# ASP.NET MVC 5 application on Windows Server 2008 Standard

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-mvc-5, server

I've developed an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I've successfully deployed it to the a server of Windows Sever 2008 R2 Enterprise. But When I try to deploy it to the Windows Server 2008 Standard, it shows an Internal Server Error 500. I've downloaded .NET Framework 4.5, installed it and restarted my server but still I'm getting the issue.

Please can I know what are the possible reasons for this error?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So it runs on 2008 R2 Enterprise but not on 2008 Standard? Since clustering is one of the differences, does the MVC app depend on clustering?

Comment: Thanks for replying, can you please more clarify how do I get to know the dependency of clustering?

Comment: Opening the project in Visual Studio, I would start with the references and see if anything is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying, actually the problem was that I didn't published it correctly. I took a step to keep Local Copy from false to true in the references for each package and republished it. It got built. Thanks